# what is the VB6 App.HelpFile equivalent inVB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I migrated VB6 code to Vb.net and I am getting

> " 'App' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection
> level".

below is the code

```
Private Declare Function WinHelp Lib "user32" Alias "WinHelpA" (ByVal hWnd As Integer, ByVal lpHelpFile As String, ByVal wCommand As Integer, ByVal dwData As Integer) As Integer

Public Property HelpFile() As String
    Get           
        HelpFile = App.HelpFile           

    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        
        App.HelpFile = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

I need help on this.

Comment: Windows Forms has a `Help` class so you should look into that.  Don't expect there to necessarily a direct equivalent so you can just change a name and be done.  You need to find the appropriate type(s), learn how it/they work and then write the appropriate code to achieve the functionality you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in converting a VB6 project to VB.NET, I found this [PDF File](http://kau.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:5702/FULLTEXT01.pdf) that has a lot of information about it. However, if you don't mind going through it, I found this on the bottom of the 18th page:

> "If the application has a helpfile associated to it then the solution is just to change the `app.helpfile` to the name and path of the
> helpfile. So for example if the helpfile is called name MyProject.hlp and is stored in the `c:\` directory the `app.helpfile` should simply be changed into `“c:\MyProject.hlp”`. "

So, just use another variable whose value you are going to set in the class constructor, then use it inside this property instead of `App.HelpFile`. Hope it helps.